# Placing image where i want HTML

Tags: html, css, image, position

I want to place this animated gif outside of the layout; basically I want it here:

[image]

So I want that character over where the arrows point; what do I need to do?

The website live demo: http://holamyphone.esy.es/privilegies.html

The name of the gif is "counter-dancing.gif".

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Услуги УБИТАЯ СЛАВА</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
  <style></style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="well well-small">
    <center><img alt="" title="Услуги сервера" border="0" src="/img/logo.png"></center>
  </div>
  <div id="pageAlign">
    <div class="well well-small">

      <div id="privileges">



        <!-- АДМИНКА + ВИП START -->

        <div id="privilege">
          <div class="privilegeImage" style="background: #0081ff;"><img src="/img/error.png"></div>
          <div class="privilegeName" style="color: #0081ff;">АДМИНКА + VIP</div>
          <div class="privilegePrice30">
            <ul>
              <li>30 гривен</li>
              <li>120 рублей</li>
              <li>(30 дней)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="seps" style="margin-left: 4px;"><img src="/img/seps.png" alt=""></div>
          <div class="privilegePriceForever">
            <ul>
              <li>75 гривен</li>
              <li>300 рублей</li>
              <li>(3 месяца)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeDiscription">
            <ul style="list-style: decimal; text-align: left; line-height: 30px; font-size: 13px;">
              <li><b>Доступно все 
      <br>
      </li>
      <font color="#FF8C00">[</font><font color="#008000">Админ</font><font color="#FF8C00">]</font> и <font color="#FF8C00">[</font><font color="#008000">VIP</font><font color="#FF8C00">]</font></b></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeScreen"><a href="/">Скриншоты</a></div>
        </div>

        <!-- АДМИНКА + ВИП END -->

        <!-- АДМИНКА START -->

        <div id="privilege">
          <div class="privilegeImage" style="background: #ee6748;"><img src="/img/error.png"></div>
          <div class="privilegeName" style="color: #ee6748;">АДМИНКА</div>
          <div class="privilegePrice30">
            <ul>
              <li>30 гривен</li>
              <li>120 рублей</li>
              <li>(30 дней)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="seps" style="margin-left: 4px;"><img src="/img/seps.png" alt=""></div>
          <div class="privilegePriceForever">
            <ul>
              <li>75 гривен</li>
              <li>300 рублей</li>
              <li>(3 месяца)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeDiscription">
            <ul style="list-style: decimal; text-align: left; line-height: 30px; font-size: 13px;">
              <li><b>amxmodmenu</b>
                <br> [Меню админа]</li>
              <li>
                <p>
                  <font color="#FF0000"><b>Цветной чат</b></font>
                </p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p><b>Префикс <font color="#FF8C00">[</font><font color="#008000">Админ</font><font color="#FF8C00">]</font> в чате</b></p>
              </li>
              <li><b>Иммунитет от кика, бана и т.п</b></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeScreen"><a href="/">Скриншоты</a></div>
        </div>

        <!-- АДМИНКА END -->

        <!-- VIP START -->

        <div id="privilege">
          <div class="privilegeImage" style="background: #b165e6;"><img src="/img/error.png"></div>
          <div class="privilegeName" style="color: #b165e6;">VIP</div>
          <div class="privilegePrice30">
            <ul>
              <li>15 гривен</li>
              <li>60 рублей</li>
              <li>(30 дней)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="seps" style="margin-left: 4px;"><img src="/img/seps.png" alt=""></div>
          <div class="privilegePriceForever">
            <ul>
              <li>40 гривен</li>
              <li>160 рублей</li>
              <li>(3 месяца)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeDiscription">
            <ul style="list-style: decimal; text-align: left; line-height: 30px; font-size: 13px;">
              <li><b>vipmenu</b>
                <br> [Меню оружия]</li>
              <li>
                <p>
                  <font color="#FF0000"><b>Цветной чат</b></font>
                </p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p><b>Префикс <font color="#FF8C00">[</font><font color="#008000">VIP</font><font color="#FF8C00">]</font> в чате</b></p>
              </li>
              <li><b>Иммунитет от кика, бана и т.п</b></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeScreen"><a href="/">Скриншоты</a></div>
        </div>

        <!-- VIP END -->



        <!-- ПРЕФИКС START -->

        <div id="privilege">
          <div class="privilegeImage"><img src="/img/error.png"></div>
          <div class="privilegeName">НЕДОСТУПНО</div>
          <div class="privilegePrice30">
            <ul>
              <li>0 гривен</li>
              <li>0 рублей</li>
              <li>(0 дней)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="seps"><img src="/img/seps.png" alt=""></div>
          <div class="privilegePriceForever">
            <ul>
              <li>0 гривен</li>
              <li>0 рублей</li>
              <li>(Навсегда)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeDiscription">Данная функция не доступна</div>
          <div class="privilegeScreen"><a href="/">НЕДОСТУПНО</a></div>
        </div>

        <!-- ПРЕФИКС END -->


        <!-- НЕДОСТУПНО START -->

        <div id="privilege">
          <div class="privilegeImage"><img src="/img/error.png"></div>
          <div class="privilegeName">НЕДОСТУПНО</div>
          <div class="privilegePrice30">
            <ul>
              <li>0 гривен</li>
              <li>0 рублей</li>
              <li>(0 дней)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="seps"><img src="/img/seps.png" alt=""></div>
          <div class="privilegePriceForever">
            <ul>
              <li>0 гривен</li>
              <li>0 рублей</li>
              <li>(Навсегда)</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="privilegeDiscription">Данная функция не доступна</div>
          <div class="privilegeScreen"><a href="/">НЕДОСТУПНО</a></div>
        </div>

        <!-- НЕДОСТУПНО END -->
      </div>
      <div id="botButton"><a href="/">Как купить услугу?</a></div>
      <div id="vkLink"><a href="http://vk.com/set_lore_play" target="_blank">Наша группа Вконтакте</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="contactsBlock">
      <div id="contacts">Главный Администратор сервера:
        <admin><b>AK_47</b></admin>
      </div><br><br>
      <div id="feedback">
        Контакты для связи со мной:
        <ul>
          <li><i></i>tamapenko</li>
          <div class="counter-dancing"><img src="/img/counter-dancing.gif" alt=""></div>
          <li><i style="background-position-y: 16px;"></i>vk.com/set_lore_play</li>
        </ul>
      </div><br><br>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have a small typo in your URL: 'privilegies' should be spelled 'privileges,' (irrelevant to your problem though); it goes to the correct page on your site, so far as I can tell, it's just that it's misspelled.

Comment: The code is correct. The spelling is tagged to the same css spelling so it all works :) but thank you anyways

Answer (score 3):

Add following CSS to your code

```
.counter-dancing{
position:relative;
left:-30px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, or set a negative value for margin-left

Answer (score 2):

```css
#feedback {
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
}

.counter-dancing {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="feedback">
  Контакты для связи со мной:
  <div class="counter-dancing"><img src="/img/counter-dancing.gif" alt=""></div>
  <ul>
    <li><i></i>tamapenko</li>
    <li><i style="background-position-y: 16px;"></i>vk.com/set_lore_play</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the code itself is wrong. it's invalid HTML. you are not allowed to use any other tag directly inside `<ul>`.

so you need to change your HTML like this:

```
<div id="feedback">
   Контакты для связи со мной:
  <div class="counter-dancing"><img src="/img/counter-dancing.gif" alt=""></div>
    <ul>
        <li><i></i>tamapenko</li>
        <li><i style="background-position-y: 16px;"></i>vk.com/set_lore_play</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and CSS should be something like this:

```
#feedback {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 213px;
}
.counter-dancing {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px; // set this position as you want
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 20px; // set this margin as much gap you need to the right
}
```

this should do your job. check.

Comment: So where would you want me to put the html? After ul or?

Comment: yes, after `<ul>` or before it. you can see the HTML I have done for you above

Comment: I put the css in. Nothing really happened

Comment: it looks like `.counter-dancing` was spelled incorrectly in my code. i have updated, please check now

Comment: Hey i apriciate you're help sincerly. But it is not working. check it out: http://holamyphone.esy.es/privilegies.html

Comment: can you replace your html and css with the one i have posted in snippet?

Comment: change the code and upload in that site, i will look. here are 2 ul and 2 .feedback http://prntscr.com/eeh39l

Comment: Finally. Please don't forget to mark the best answer so other can know about it

Answer (score 1):

you want this?

[image: Soldier on Left]

then you need to make following changes in your `main.css` in class `.counter-dancing`.

like this:

```
.counter-dancing {
   float: left;
   margin-left: -150px;
   margin-top: -100px;
}
```

it would do the job..

Comment: glad to know that :) . please accept this answer if it worked for you (click on accept button)

Comment: and a little reputation would be appreciated

Comment: I don't see that button?

Comment: here [http://prntscr.com/eehlk7](http://prntscr.com/eehlk7) on the left side of the answer

Comment: Yeah i already pressed that.. Thats what it says http://prntscr.com/eehn81

Comment: ah i forgot, you need at least 15 reputation for giving positive feedback, but still you can accept the answer by clicking the "tick" under the voting buttons

Comment: and now you can coz i see you just got your 15 reputation :)